# Proving a property for a metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. And it also has the property

$d(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\leq  d(x_1,y_1)+d(x_2,y_2).$

Is it also true that $d(x_1+x_2+...+x_n,y_1+y_2+...+y_n)\leq  d(x_1,y_1)+d(x_2,y_2)+...+d(x_n,y_n)$?

Comment: I think it can be shown by induction easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.

$d(x_1+x_2+...+x_n,y_1+y_2+...+y_n)\leq d(x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-1},y_1+y_2+...+y_{n-1})+d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-2},y_1+y_2+...+y_{n-2})+d(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})+d(x_n,y_n)\leq ...\leq  d(x_1,y_1)+d(x_2,y_2)+...+d(x_n,y_n)$

Answer (score 1):

I think an induction does the job, you want to prove that for all $n\geq 2$ you have :

$$\forall x_i,y_i\text{, } d(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,\sum_{i=1}^ny_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^nd(x_i,y_i) $$

Well, for $n=2$ it is the proprerty you assume to be true and then for $n>2$, assuming the result is true for $n-1$ :

$$\text{If } X:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\text{ and }Y:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i$$

$$\text{ then }d(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,\sum_{i=1}^ny_i)=d(X+x_n,Y+y_n)\leq d(X,Y)+d(x_n,y_n)$$

Using the $n=2$ case, then using the $n-1$ case by induction hypothesis :

$$d(X,Y)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}d(x_i,y_i)$$

So finally you have :

$$d(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,\sum_{i=1}^ny_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}d(x_i,y_i)+d(x_n,y_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}d(x_i,y_i)$$

You conclude by induction principle.